# Unable to suggest edit, why?

Tags: support, suggested-edits, android-app

I just answered [this](https://boardgames.stackexchange.com/questions/40089/find-spell-cards-self-banish-or-cards-banish-spell-in-grave) question back on Board and Card Games.

I saw that the post could use some love, and proceeded to suggest an edit (still don't have edit privileges on that site). However I was unable to submit it, as an indication stated *"User cannot suggest edits to this question"*:

[image]

I then tried to do it **off the mobile app**, but found that the *question doesn't have an Edit option* on the browser (something I have never noticed). Stranger still is that on mobile there was option to edit:

[image]

**Anybody knows why this happened?** Perhaps something I did wrong, or something related to the fact that it was the first post from that user. Are there other ways I can suggest an edit to such posts?

Comment: There's already a pending edit.

Comment: @Catija really? Interesting, didn't noticed that from my mobile nor on pc browser...

Comment: Thanks @Glorfindel accepted that dupe as the reason

Comment: The other one is closed, better not use it as duplicate target. Since this one here now got a decent answer, better close the other way around, if anything.

Comment: @ShadowtheHedgehogWizard ok, indeed the other one only got solutions in comments, this may be a better target for future reference.

Comment: Well too late now, it's locked since it was migrated. :/

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can't submit an edit to a post that already has a pending edit. Most of the time, that's the explanation. If you use the full site view, you get a notice that says as much.

[image: pending edit note]

What you want to fix may already be done in this edit and until someone clears it, you can't submit another edit.

Comment: Seems correct, thanks for your support :) Too bad my edit was lost, let's hope the pending one is good

Comment: Catija, do you know of a reason why a user wouldn't be shown the same notice as is shown on the full site view? The notice "User cannot suggest edits to this question" almost seems to me as if the user is _prohibited_ from suggesting edits to _this_ particular question (it isn't indicated why that question is special either). I find it impossible to be able to guess the reason (that a suggested edit was pending) without having a look at this Meta.SE post beforehand. Thoughts? Is this bad UX, or just me interpreting things improperly?

Comment: @GaurangTandon The app has a completely different code base, from what I understand. The text is shorter, likely to fit on a single line.

Comment: Imho, less space should not mean that we show users a message that's likely to confuse them. A better message could have been - "another edit is awaiting approval" - with the usual red background. The red color and stopped progress would signify to the user that there's an error. The message would give them the reason.

Comment: You asked why and I guessed... I don't know that's the reason... but, @GaurangTandon I'm not in control of that, and they're not doing any work on the apps right now, so feel free to post a bug report suggesting that or some other solution they might implement when they're freed up enough to have the time. :)

Comment: Oh, alright. Thanks for the quick responses :-)